# Facebook Access Token Expired - iOS 6 Social Framework

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-access-token

I'm making an app based on iOS6 Social Framework...it was working fine but now after few months got an weird error.

My NSLog of imported JSON Facebook data to a NSDictionary is:

```
profiledictionary: {
error = {
code = 190;
"error_subcode" = 463;
message = "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1365610034. The current unix time is 1366032783.";
type = OAuthException;
```

Seems my access token has expired, but isn't iOS6 Social Framework supposed to take care of it automatically?

Any ideas about how can I solve it and also avoid future problems like that, so I can safe publish a real app?

Answer (score 13):

finally got it...was necessary to check if NSDictionary had an object named "error" (in this case Facebook error about token expired), and if so call a method to renew ACAccount:

```
if([self.profileDictionary objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
{
[self attemptRenewCredentials]; 
}

-(void)attemptRenewCredentials{
    [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)self.facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            switch (renewResult) {
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:
                    NSLog(@"Good to go");
                    [self getFacebookAccount];
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                    NSLog(@"User declined permission");
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                    NSLog(@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            //handle error
            NSLog(@"error from renew credentials%@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your question and answer today.  You just saved my skin!!!  Where on Earth did you find this out?  Thanks so much.